# Detail page route gives error

Tags: 8, routes

In **my_module.routing.yml**

```
my_module.detail:
  path: '/module/{id}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module\Controller\DetailController::view'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

In template twig file I'm calling via

```
<a href="{{ path('my_module.detail', {'id': item.id }) }}">Test</a>
```

Here my Id is not Integer It consists of string like `AzT13AAa`

So when I access it gives error like

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException:
>   Parameter "id" for route "my_module.detail" must match "[^/]++" (""
>   given) to generate a corresponding URL. in
>   Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 202 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).

Comment: Does item.id produce a value? The error sounds like it isn’t.

Comment: Yes, is item a content entity? Then twig might confuse it with the id field object ,which is not a value. Try item.id() in that case, try prining item.id in your template to see what it is

Comment: Ok let me check for value